# code to Look at rows and return the value for the highest number for a user

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table(Below is a sample of what it contains) that shows the userId plus various milestones and admission stages. What I need to do this to look at the highest number in milestone_stage_number for that user and returns the value of milestone, admission stage and milestone_latest_stage. so in the example below the query should only return one line for userid 1 with milestone_stoge_number =4 (which is the max number for that person) and return accepted for the admission stage, milestione_lates_stage = emailed and milestone= emailed. In my actual table  I have over 12000 users but I need the query to just return one row per user with the information for the maximum stage Number of that user. I hope this is clear what I need to achieve so if I have use 2 five times only returns the row for the highest numve=ber in Milestone_stage_number and hence after running the query I get one row for user 1 and one row for user 2.

my table is called applicants

```
Person_id   Milestone    admission_stage   milestone_latest_stage   milestone_stage_number
1           Under Review Accepted          Accepted                 2
1           emailed      accepted          emailed                  4
1           offered      accepted          accepted                 3
1           submitted     reviewed         offered                  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use a qualify and a window function

```sql
SELECT * FROM applicants
QUALIFY MAX(milestone_stage_number) OVER (PARTITION BY Person_id) = milestone_stage_number
```